# JDOM: Unexpectedly converting to upper case

Tags: jdom

I have xml which is processed by JDOM library. One part of xml is:

```
<fo:inline xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">Mytitle</fo:inline>
```

In output pdf 'Mytitle' is instead shown as 'MYTITLE'.
It's a legacy code and I don't have much idea of it.

So what can be the reason for this change?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not JDOM that is causing this. An [XSL_FO](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/) processor (maybe [this](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)) is transforming the XML document to PDF.